# Aggregate values in ElastAlert rules

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert

I need to write an ElastAlert rule that aggregates the values of events. The 'value' is one of fields in the ES document. 
For example, I need the total of all values, or the average.

I'm new to Python so was wondering if there are examples for such rules anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

For example, if you want an alert to be triggered when a specific value aggregated among documents reaches a threshold, you could implement your own rule that does that.

First create a file called **elastalert_modules/my_rules.py**, next to an **__ init__.py** file, as the documentation states.

Then in **my_rules.py** you can write the following:

```
from elastalert.ruletypes import RuleType

class CountValuesRule(RuleType):

    tracked_values = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
    counts = {key: 0 for key in tracked_values}

    # From elastalert docs:
    #     add_data will be called each time Elasticsearch is queried.
    #     data is a list of documents from Elasticsearch, sorted by timestamp,
    #     including all the fields that the config specifies with "include"
    def add_data(self, data):

        def should_trigger(document):
            # here decide if value in counts should trigger alert, for example:
            if self.counts['value1'] > 1000
                return True
            return False

        for document in data:
            # Increment tracked values
            for value in self.tracked_values:
                self.counts[value] += document.get(value, 0)

            if should_trigger(document):
                self.add_match(document)
                # Stop checking other values
                break

    # The results of get_match_str will appear in the alert text
    def get_match_str(self, match):
        return "A value has reached specified threshold. Values: %s" % (str(self.counts))

    # From elastalert docs:
    # garbage_collect is called indicating that ElastAlert has already been run up to timestamp
    # It is useful for knowing that there were no query results from Elasticsearch because
    # add_data will not be called with an empty list
    def garbage_collect(self, timestamp):
        pass
```

Finally include this custom rule in a rule you are configuring, like this:

```
name: Your rule name
es_host: Your host
es_port: Your port
type: "elastalert_modules.my_rules.CountValuesRule"
```